# Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: (DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to launch Chrome with a URL, the browser launches but it does nothing after that.

Seeing below error in my Eclipse console:

```
Starting ChromeDriver 112.0.5615.49 (bd2a7bcb881c11e8cfe3078709382934e3916914-refs/branch-heads/5615@{#936}) on port 24598
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited normally.
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.) 
Host info: host: 'ITCHAUNOTE', ip: '192.168.1.15'
Build info: version: '4.8.3', revision: 'e5e76298c3'
System info: **os.name: 'Windows 10'**, os.arch: 'amd64', **os.version: '10.0', java.version: '17.0.6'**
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Command: [null, newSession {capabilities=[Capabilities {browserName: chrome, goog:chromeOptions: {args: [--remote-allow-origins=*], extensions: []}}], desiredCapabilities=Capabilities {browserName: chrome, goog:chromeOptions: {args: [--remote-allow-origins=*], extensions: []}}}]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:148)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:106)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:67)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:165)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.invokeExecute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:183)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:158)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:543)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:229)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:157)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chromium.ChromiumDriver.<init>(ChromiumDriver.java:101)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:88)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:84)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:73)
    at ChromeTest.main(ChromeTest.java:13)
```

Selenium Code:

```java
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;

public class ChromeTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException{
    
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Selenium\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
        
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
        
        driver.get("https://www.google.com/travel/flights");
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        driver.quit();

    }

}
```

My configuration:

- Chrome browser Version: 112.0.5615.49 (Official Build) (64-bit)
- Chrome Driver: ChromeDriver 112.0.5615.49
- Selenium-Java version: 4.8.3

Note: Code works fine in other browsers Edge, Firefox but not in Chrome

- OS: Microsoft Windows 10 Enterprise
- System Type: x64-based PC

Solution tried so far:

1. Works fine when using code with setting Chrome options as shown below. But it runs in chomeheadless mode which I don't want. I want to run my tests only in Chrome browser.

````java
  System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Selenium\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");        
          // WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
  
      ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
      options.addArguments("--no-sandbox"); // Bypass OS security model
      options.addArguments("--headless");
      options.addArguments("start-maximized"); // open Browser in maximized mode 
      options.addArguments("disable-infobars"); // disabling infobars
      options.addArguments("--disable-extensions"); // disabling extensions 
      options.addArguments("--disable-gpu"); // applicable to windows os only 
      options.addArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage"); // overcome limited resource problems
      options.addArguments("--remote-allow-origins=*");
      driver = new ChromeDriver(options);      
      driver.get("https://www.google.com/travel/flights"); 
      Thread.sleep(5000); 
      driver.quit();
  ```

2. Have tried older versions of Chrome browser, Chrome driver, and Selenium jar but no luck.
````